# Sing app bundle with lost keystore how to update?

Tags: unity-game-engine, keystore

i lost my keystore and i sent email to google the replied me and,
I have receive email from google

**New upload certificate fingerprints:
MD5:  3B:04:58:F3:8C:CF:24:17:B3:BA:E6:3F:2B:63:2C:6B
SHA1: D1:5A:FD:E7:64:80:86:C9:25:26:72:54:57:B3:EE:9F:97:38:03:87**

i am using unity i don't know how to sign my apk with these certificates ?

Answer (score 0):

This is just fingerprints, you can't create signing key using them, you can only check if exist keystore match fingerprints.